# Entity Framework removes dataset in database instead of delete the link between the entities

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the situation that i track and trace storage situations. A storage-location can contain many stock elements. After a storage location was emptied the stock elements should still exist for statistics.

This is my code:

```
                var storageElement = this.StorageElementManager.ReadStorageElement(Shelf_Level_Box_Code);
                
                foreach (var stockElement in storageElement.StockElements)
                {
                    stockElement.DateOfRemovalFromStorage = DateTime.Now;
                    stockElement.StorageDuration = stockElement.DateOfRemovalFromStorage - stockElement.DateOfPlacementFromStorage;
                }

                
                storageElement = this.StorageElementManager.UpdateStorageElement(storageElement);

                
                storageElement.StockElements = null;

                //This update removes the stock elements from the database
                storageElement = this.StorageElementManager.UpdateStorageElement(storageElement);
```

The last update deletes the stockelements from the database. But i only wanna destroy the relationship between the elements. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that i've linked in my entity the relationship as required. This situation created the behaviour that setting a object reference to null automatically deletes the database entry.

Wrong code was:

```
[Required]
public StorageElement StorageElement { get; set; }
```

Correct code is:

```
public StorageElement StorageElement { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are doing it , at first you deleted all StockElements

```
storageElement.StockElements = null;
```

after this you saved deletion

```
 storageElement = this.StorageElementManager.UpdateStorageElement(storageElement);
```

remove this code at all

```
  storageElement.StockElements = null;
   storageElement = this.StorageElementManager.UpdateStorageElement(storageElement);
```

Comment: I understand your post and i know that this code is my problem. But anyway what kind of code should i use to get the correct solution? I need to unlink the stockElements from the storageElement.

Comment: But its necessary that the entry still exists in the table.